# report generation based on selected fields

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, sql

What I currently do is that I display all the columns for the searched records in a div with id of searchresults using AJAX and then i give a print option to print those records. Now I want to be able to select a set of columns (for this purpose i have provided all columns with a checkbox) and print only the selected ones. I can get the selected columns in a php file but how do I frame a query out of those selected column values. I mean there can so many different combinations possible. Code till now..

```
                <?php




                 echo ' <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#cd0000; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="facultyname" /><br>FACULTY</td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#de0000; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="departmentname" /><br>DEPT.</td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#ef0000; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="coursename" /><br>COURSE</td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#ff0000; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="year" /><br>YEAR </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#f50853; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="semester" /><br>SEM. </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#f5087e; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="studentname" /><br>NAME  </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#f508dd; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="enrollment" /><br>ENROLL. </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#c108f5; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="courseseatcategory" /><br>SEAT CATEGORY</td> 
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#7e08f5; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="gender" /><br>GENDER </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#3f08f5; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="dob" /><br>D.O.B</td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#2f95f4; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="religion" /><br>RELIGION </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#9f4ef0; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="category" /><br>CATEGORY </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#ee4ef0; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="country" /><br>COUNTRY </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#f70767; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="state" /><br>STATE </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#ef4ef0; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="internal" /><br>INTERNAL </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#2e95f3; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="ph" /><br>PH </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#7e08f1; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="dor" /><br>D.O.R </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#f508aa; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="supervisior" /><br>SUPERVISOR </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#ff0000; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="cosupervisor" /><br>COSUPERVISOR </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#9f4ef0; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="titleofthesis" /><br>TITLE of THESIS</td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#2f95f4; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="mou" /><br>MOU </td>
                        <td class="lab searchtableheader" style="color:#7e08f5; padding:5px;"><input type="checkbox" name="print" value="mouinstitute" /><br>MOU INSTITUTE </td>

                        </tr>       ';?>
```

JavaScript to print:

```
function printDiv()
{
  var divToPrint=document.getElementById('searchresults');
  newWin= window.open("");
  newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
  newWin.print();
  newWin.close();
}
```

Comment: i am thinking to get the selected columns and query only those columns from the database and then write the result in the new page using the printDiv

Comment: but not able to write the query out of all the possible combinations of the selected columns.. :/

Answer (score 1):

First off you need to change name="print" to name="print[]" so php can pick up all of the selected values.

Whether you use post or get on submitting the information you will need to loop through the values sent. The information will be in the print array.

```
$prn = $_POST['print'];
$sql = "SELECT ";
$flds = "";
foreach( $prn as $p ) {
  if( $flds != "" ) $flds .= ",";
  $flds .= $p
}
$sql .= $flds . " FROM ....
```

Please not the code is untested but it should give you a starting point

Comment: Thnx jeff..that exactly what I was looking for, I was not able to frame this foreach loop properly. Lemme check if it works now.. 
By the way, thanks.. :)

Comment: i think we will have to check if the field is selected using isset() here.